# Ошибка при создании дочернего процесса

Tags: linux, c, bash

Помогите исправить ошибку

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    if (argc == 2) {
        char command[100] = {0};

        sprintf(command, "./test.sh %s", argv[1]);
        system(command);
        sleep(5);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

test.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
    gnome-terminal -e $($1)
```

в итоге открывается новый терминал с ошибкой[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вообще суть такая: ввести текст-cmd команду и отправить ее в скрипт, но главное чтобы исполнялась в новом терминале

Comment: А что в `argv` передаете?

Comment: gcc 2lab_2.c -o 2lab && ./2lab ls
передаю ls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в `./test.sh`

Ловите:

```
#!/bin/bash
#echo arg = "'$1'"
gnome-terminal -- sh -c "$1; cat"
```

В таком виде можно выполнять команду даже с аргументами.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac != 2)
    exit((fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s command\n", av[0]), 1));
  char *cmd;
  asprintf(&cmd, "./test.sh \"%s\"", av[1]);

  system(cmd);

  return puts("Bye!") == EOF;
}
```

Транслируем и запускаем

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc t-term.c && ./a.out "ls -l a.out t-term.c"
Bye!
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

и в окошке `gnome-terminal` (кстати, он как демон уходит от родителя, поэтому `sleep()` не нужен) наблюдаем:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 avp avp 8576 Dec  4 00:39 a.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 avp avp  296 Dec  4 00:34 t-term.c
```

Comment: Можете сказать что делают ключи —sh -c, а то не гуглится

Comment: Ключ `--` как всегда означает конец списка опций, `sh -c ...` -- запустить в терминале shell и в нем выполнить список команд. Гуглится просто --  [man gnome-terminal](https://www.unix.com/man-page/All/1/gnome-terminal/), но можно набрать `gnome-terminal --help-all`. Если попробовать `gnome-terminal -e command`, то вылезает сообщение, что -e depricated и совет передавать команду после `--`. Зачем cat после ls понятно?

Comment: Да, это просто. Спасибо большое! Вы очень помогли.